# Is it better for me to use a for loop in Bash or C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, networking

I'm writing a program to "break" one of my company's devices. The issue is that too much TCP traffic on the device shuts its port down and we need to try to replicate this. Originally, my thought has been to use the for loop in C, but I also think it's probably more representative of the failures that are occurring if there are more simultaneous connections. So my thought now is to create a bash script that will execute the program multiple times.

The real issue is that we are seeing the failures occur because TCP connections are being opened and closed for every command that comes in.

So I have a simple C program that opens a connection, sends a command to the device, gets the response, and then closes the connection. My original thought was to create a for loop inside the C code that performs all the connections, but it wouldn't happen simultaneously. So I wonder how much, if anything I lose with a bash script that executes the compiled C program in the for loop.

Comment: There's also the GNU `parallel` tool - https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/, this may help you launch multiple simultaneous runs of your C program.  If it were me, I'd use `bash`, but perhaps make the C program take a few command line arguments to make each run a little different somehow.  [And check to make sure your device hasn't run out of sockets because they're all stuck in FIN_WAIT_2 or suchlike].

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen GNU parallel before. I'll have to check it out. I'm not certain if it's as portable as C and bash will be for me. I think I'll stick with the simple C program and a bash script.

Comment: Why write any code? Use netcat.

Comment: Have a look at `parallel --embed` when building the bash script.